# Does Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP4 have support for TLS1.2 in its setup or there another cumulative update having TLS1.2 support?

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2

We have SQL Server 2012 SP4 and we need TLS1.2 support also for our software. But I am not able to find the cumulative update setup for SP4. Is TLS1.2 already included in Microsoft SQL SP4 setup?

Comment: You had your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft clarified this here:[TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)

> Use the following table to determine whether your current version of SQL Server already has support for TLS 1.2 or whether you have to download an update to enable TLS 1.2 support. Use the download links in the table to obtain the server updates that are applicable to your environment.

Note Builds that are later than those listed in this table also support TLS 1.2.

[image]